# Javascript replace characters of an element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to replace characters within an array of strings.

so far i have this:

```
stuff= ["uyuuyu", "76gyuhj***", "uiyghj", "56tyg", "juijjujh***"];

for(var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
{
    if(stuff[i].indexOf('***') != -1)
    {
        // this is where i guess the replacing would go
    }
}
```

I figured out that i can use this code to display with element in the array has the characters *** now want to replace the `***` characters with a number so that it outputs a new array ( the same array but modified) that looks like :

```
  stuff= ["uyuuyu", "76gyuhj0", "uiyghj", "56tyg", "juijjujh0"];
```

I can't seem to figure out how to replace the characters within that array without effecting the rest of the array

Comment: How is the number determined (is it always 0)? What to do with more than 3 asterisks?

Comment: What do you mean by "effecting the rest of the array"?

Comment: assume the number will always be 0 and there will always be 3 asterisks. i should update that into the post

Comment: `stuff.map( x => x.replace('***','0'))`

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly i just  mean without rearranging the elements. so it always stays in the same position. the only way i thought of doing it was to remove that part of the array and then use replace on the string and then push it back in somehow? or splice. i hope that makes sense

Comment: Is it important that the original array is mutated? Or can you create a new one which is reassigned to the original variable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Also consider `.replace(/\*\*\*/g, '0')` if you want to replace multiple occurrences of `***`. (The below code only replaces the first occurrence in each string.)

```js
stuff= ["uyuuyu", "76gyuhj***", "uiyghj", "56tyg", "juijjujh***"];

for(var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
{
    stuff[i] = stuff[i].replace('***', '0');
}

console.log(stuff);
```

Note that there's no need to check `indexOf`. If the substring isn't present, the `replace` just doesn't change anything, so you can just apply the `replace` to every string.

Comment: Or use regex and it will replace every `***` with 0 - `stuff[i] = stuff[i].replace(/(\*\*\*)/g, '0');`

Answer (score 9):

you can use javascript `map` as below

```
 var newStuff =stuff.map(function(item,index){
  return item.replace('***','0')

});

console.log(newStuff) //["uyuuyu", "76gyuhj0", "uiyghj", "56tyg", "juijjujh0"]
```

es2015 (es6) with arrow function

```
var newStuff = stuff.map(item => item.replace('***','0'));
```

Comment: I really like this way! thank you. going to accept a different answer because the name of the array didn't change. which is a little better for me in what i'm trying to do. but i will keep a note of your answer too. learned a lot from it

Answer (score 1):

```
var stuff= ["uyuuyu", "76gyuhj***", "uiyghj", "56tyg", "juijjujh***"];

for(var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
{
    if(stuff[i].indexOf('***') != -1)
{
        stuff[i] = stuff[i].replace('***','0')
    // this is where i guess the replacing would go
}
console.log(stuff[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Use replace function to modify the strings

```
stuff= ["uyuuyu", "76gyuhj***", "uiyghj", "56tyg", "juijjujh***"];

for(var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++)
{
        stuff[i] = stuff[i].replace('***', '');
}
```

Comment: Check condition before replace is redundant.

Comment: @Lucas Costa Ya you are right. I have modified the code

Comment: How would you accomplish this on a 2d array?